# Optaplanner - large datasets with millions of rows

Tags: optaplanner

There are a couple of threads discussing the scalability of Optaplanner, and I am wondering what's the recommended approach to deal with very large datasets when it comes to millions of rows?

As this blog discussed I am already using heuristic (Simulated Annealing + Tabu Search). The search space of cloud balancing problem is c^p, but the feasible space is unknown/NP-complete.

http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/27/IsTheSearchSpaceOfAnOptimizationProblemReallyThatBig.html

The problem I am trying to solve is similar to cloud balancing. But the main difference is in the input data, besides a list of computers and a list of processes, there is also a big two dimensional 'score list/table' which has the scores for each possible combinations that needs to be loaded into memory.

In other words, except for the constraints between computers and processes that the planning needs to satisfy, different valid combinations yield various scores and the higher the score the better.

It's a simple problem but when it comes to hundreds of computers, 100k+ processes and the score table has a million+ combinations, it needs a lot of memory. Even though I could allocate more memory to increase the heap size, the planning could become very slow and struggling, as the steps are sorted with custom planning variable/entity comparator classes.

A straight-forward solution is to divide the dataset into smaller subsets, run each of them individually and then combine the results, so that I could have multiple machines to run at the same time and each machine runs on multi-threads. The biggest drawback of this approach is the result produced is far away from optimal.

I am wondering is there any other better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The MachineReassignment example also has a big "score combination" matrix. OptaPlanner doesn't care about that - those are just problem facts and the DRL quickly matches the combination(s) that is picked for an assignment. The `Solver.solve()` causes no big memory consumption or performance impact.
However, **loading the problem** in your code (before calling `Solver.solve()`) does **cause a huge memory consumption**: Understand that if `n = 20k`, then `n² = 400m` and an `int` takes of up 4 bytes, so for **20 000 elements that matrix is `1.6 GB`**  in its most efficient uncompressed form `int[][]` (both in Java and C++!). So for 20k reserve 2GB RAM, for 40k reserve 8GB RAM for 80k reserve 32 GB RAM. That scales badly.

As for dealing with these big problems, I use combinations of techniques such as Nearby Selection (see my blog article on that), Partitioned Search (what you described, it will be supported out of the box in 7, but I 've implemented it for customers in a CustomPhase), Limited Selection Construction Heuristics (need to research that further, the plumbing is there, usually overkill), ... Partitioned Search does indeed exclude optimal solutions, but above 10k planning entities the trade-off quality vs time taking clearly favors Partitioned Search given a reasonable solving time (minutes/hours/days instead of millenia). The trick is to keep the size of each partition big enough, above 1k entities (hence the use NearbySelection). Score calculation speed also matters a lot, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, Geoffrey. I have already implemented the valueSelector and entitySelector in the unionMoveSelector, and both selectors using sorted selection order with comparator classes. As long as I understood, implementing the Nearby Selection method would replace my current sorting selection method. Additionally, I need to define what's the 'distance' concept in a MachineReassignment context?

Comment: I got an error message saying 'The valueSelectorConfig (ValueSelectorConfig(XXX)) with resolvedCacheType (PHASE) and resolvedSelectionOrder (ORIGINAL) needs to be based on an EntityIndependentValueSelector (FromEntityPropertyValueSelector(XXX)). Check your @ValueRangeProvider annotations.', when trying to config the CH with the advanced configuration details of Weakest Fit Decreasing as document 9.8.2 (R6.4) described. Is it a bug to be fixed in 7.0.0.Beta1? What's the workaround?