# OptaPlanner large dataset issue

Tags: optaplanner

i just wanted to know that why optaplanner raises an exception on my data. is it becuase of its limitations? my CVRP data-set contains 1800 points requiring 33 vehicles. data-set is something like this:

```
NAME :  X-n1784-k33             
COMMENT :   morteza 2019                
TYPE :  CVRP                
DIMENSION : 1784                    
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE :  EUC_2D              
CAPACITY : 330                  
NODE_COORD_SECTION                  
1   369 715         
2   0   858         
3   1   871         
4   1   872     
......
1783    544 625         
1784    596 646         
DEMAND_SECTION                  
1 0                 
2 14                    
3 2     
......
1784 25                 
DEPOT_SECTION                   
    1               
    -1              
EOF
```

i have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681988/optaplanner-large-datasets-with-millions-of-rows) before, but i think it is not the problem.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception in inputFile (D:\Projects\POWERBI\algorithm\routing\12 - existing solutions\CVRP existing codes\x_N1784_K33_1.vrp)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.common.persistence.AbstractTxtSolutionImporter.readSolution(AbstractTxtSolutionImporter.java:56)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.importSolution(SolutionBusiness.java:271)
 at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame$ImportAction.actionPerformed(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:548) at .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception you sent me over email:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception in inputFile (D:\Projects\POWERBI\algorithm\routing\12 - existing solutions\CVRP existing codes\x_N1784_K33_1.vrp)
...
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The number of demands with 0 demand (55) differs from the number of depots (1).
at org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.persistence.VehicleRoutingImporter$VehicleRoutingInputBuilder.readVrpWebDepotList(VehicleRoutingImporter.java:356)
...
```

It seems that VehicleRoutingImporter can't properly parse your input file:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The number of demands with 0 demand (55) differs from the number of depots (1).
```